# BigQuery_Month to Date period

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a problem to query data like this. I want to compare automatically period month to date; for example, I want to compare time range between 1/10 - current_date (28/10) & 1/9 - 28/9 & 1/8 - 28/8 and all month before.
I have code:

```
WITH
cte_time AS (
SELECT Day
FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(DATE("2022-08-01"),CURRENT_DATE("+7"), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) Day
)
,cte_timerange AS(
SELECT
"Monthly" TimeRange,
EXTRACT(Month FROM DAY) Period,
DATE_TRUNC(Day,month) MinDate,
DATE_ADD(DATE_TRUNC(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 day), (day)), INTERVAL DATE_DIFF(CURRENT_DATE(), DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(),(day)), DAY) DAY) as prior_period_end
group by 1,2,3,period
)
select * from cte_timerange
```

But the output is just 1 result (28/10) for each month. I am so stuck for this. Can anyone solve this similar problem before?

[image]

Thanks a lot for supporting me.

Here is the result that I want.

[image]

Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider below.

```sql
SELECT 'Monthly' TimeRange,
       EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Month) Period,
       Month AS MinDate,
       DATE_ADD(Month, INTERVAL EXTRACT(DAY FROM CURRENT_DATE('+7')) - 2 DAY) AS prior_period_end
  FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(DATE '2022-08-01', CURRENT_DATE('+7'), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) Month;
```

Note that **prior_period_end** doesn't include today (29/10).  If you want to include it, you can change `- 2 DAY` to `- 1 DAY`.

###### Query results

[image]

Comment: Hello there,
I'm so grateful for your help. Besides, in case, I want to separate 2 different time range, like Monthly - 8 - 2022-08-01 - 2022-08-28 UNION ALL PreviousMonthly - 9 - 2022-09-01 - 2022-09-28 UNION ALL PreviousMonthly - 8 - 2022-08-01 - 2022-08-28 and all months before. I tried to use union all but it does not work :(

Comment: @Jasmine, this is not clear to me. would you post what have you tried and the expected result in another question ?

Comment: Yay, of course. It's just about the logic of flow. Here is my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74246445/bigquery-find-group-of-customer
Thank you again for supporting me.